# How to install ubuntu desktop version on nexus 7 2013(flo)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I've already installed ubuntu touch 15.04 on my ASUS nexus7 2013. But the os works really slowly and lacks daily softwares.
So I am trying to install **desktop version** on it.However the **ubuntu-nexus7-installer** doesn't work anymore. Are there any other ways to install ubuntu desktop version on nexus7?
Thanks.